# Mpp Files to Excel Automation

Tags: excel, power-automate, mpp

It takes too long for me to export many MPP files into Excel format on a daily basis. Is there a way to make this conversion procedure automatic?

Manually I am  doing it as export into excel

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I think your question should contain a lot more information and is at risk of being closed, but, I am going to answer it anyway, and, you may not like the answer but it's very much valid.

The simple answer is .. **YES** ... however, you need to do the work to write all of the data to Excel.

LogicApps/PowerAutomate provides you with a connector which allows you to extract the data in some form and then it'd be up to you to write it out to Excel.

[image: Actions]

You could use Office Scripts to make it look exactly as you want.